# Regex to match an entire vb.net class in a multiple classes file

Tags: regex

I have a file that contains multiple vb.net classes such as:

```
Public Class AddressVerification

    Public SingleAddress As Boolean

    Public Addresses as List(Of Address)

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Address

    Public ClientId as String

    Public City as String

    Public Zip as String

End Class
```

I want to build a regular expression to grab the entire AddressVerification class and I tried the regex:

```
(\bPublic Class AddressVerification\b)|(\bEnd Class\b)
```

Global and multiline flags are turned on by default and the sample can be found at https://regex101.com/r/XQVp5v/2. How can I capture the entire AddressVerification? (picture below)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a negative lookahead is supported, you could match all the following lines that do not start with *End Class*

```
^Public Class AddressVerification(?:\r?\n(?!End Class\b).*)*\r?\nEnd Class\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `Public Class AddressVerification` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!End Class\b)` Match a newline and assert what is directly to the right is not *End Class*
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\nEnd Class\b` Match a newline followed by *End Class*

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ezoD1a/1)